# dojo.addOnLoad behaves odd on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dojo

`dojo.addOnLoad` - Google Chrome

I am working on an application from few years, for which I have given full support on firefox browser and partial support to google chrome and other browsers. Looking at customer's need and convenience I have started fixing the issues being faced while executing my application inside google chrome browser. While doing so, I have started facing strange issue with dojo 1.6.2 addOnLoad event, that gets triggered multiple time when i open my page into google chrome browser and the same code if i execute in firefox it gets triggered just once.

I have tested this behavior with

```
    Firefox 52.0.1 (64-bit) and 
    Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) 
    on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add a piece of code which simulate your issue here so we can found out what is the issue.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.addOnLoad(my_function);

function my_function() {
 alert("inside myfunction");
}
</script>

Ideally above code should alert the message for once only, but in my case it alerts it 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

`dojo.addOnLoad()` has been deprecated, please consider updating to `domReady!` module, which has several bug fixes.

> dojo.addOnLoad() has been deprecated in favor of the (equivalent)
>   dojo.ready function, and more recently, in favor of the The AMD API,
>   and the domReady! plugin. [Ref](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/addOnLoad.html).